# Discord.js say command

Tags: javascript, discord.js

### I'm working on a discord bot that has a say command. But my results are different to what I expect.

Here is my code:

```
Discord = require('discord.js');
client = new Discord.Client();
prefix = '$';
fs = require('fs');
.commands = new Discord.Collection();
commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is online!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'say') {
        client.commands.get('say').execute(message, args, Discord);
    }
});
```

say.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'say',
    description: 'The bot says thing.',
    execute(message, args, Discord) {
        message.channel.send(args);
    }
}
```

My expectations:

**User:** $say stack overflow is cool
**Bot:** stack overflow is cool

The output:

**User**: $say stack overflow is cool

**Bot**:

stack

overflow

is

cool

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that your "args" argument is an array of strings. When you send it with the send function, each element of the array will be send with a new line between them.

If you look the documentation, you can see that send() wants a [String Resolvable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NI9h.png), and an array IS a valid String Resolvable value, but it comes with a special behavior.

Try using the [join method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) on your argument before sending it. Here's an example:

```js
message.channel.send(args.join(' '));
```

Comment: "If you look the documentation, you can see that send() wants a String Resolvable" When citing from an online source, please add a link to it and also add quotes from the actual text when possible (currently there is only a link to a screenshot on a third-party website).

Comment: @kelvin my bad, the source is the discord.js documentation:

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/StringResolvable